# Make std::max_element skip element if bool flag is set

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a vector of items and a boolean flag:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Item, bool>> items;
```

I'm doing a greedy (and inneficient, I'm aware of that and it's on purpose) search of all the best items in this vector at each iteration. After each iteration I invalidate the current best item by setting the boolean flag to false. So in the next iteration this item will no longer be considered, at least that's what I'm trying to do. I want to keep this going untill all elements are false.  I get the best value with this GetYield function provided by the Item class:

```
while( std::any_of( items.begin(), items.end(),
    []( const auto& item ) { return item.second; } ) )
{
    auto max_element = std::max_element( items.begin(), items.end(),
        [&]( auto& itema, auto& itemb )
        {
                return  itema.second && itemb.second && ( itema.first.GetYield() < itemb.first.GetYield() );
        } );

    max_element->second = false;
}
```

This code hangs as soon as the first element is set to false, it keeps returning the same element over and over. How can I fix this **without** removing elements from the vector(that's the whole reason I made a pair with a boolean) ?

Comment: Side note: `std::pair` should *very rarely* be used outside of templates. Usually you want to instead define a custom `struct` with two members with meaningful names.

Comment: *search of all the best items in this vector at each iteration* -- Isn't this just a [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) you are attempting to create?

Comment: @JesperJuhl why is that?

Comment: @IRP_HANDLER Because the names "first" and "second" are pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate is incorrect.  It *should* compare two elements in the vector, and returns `false` if the first one is 'less' than the second.

There are four cases here:

- If both items are empty, then the comparison should return `false`.
- if `itemA.second` is false, the the comparison should return `true`.("empty" is less than anything)
- if `itemB.second` is false is the comparison should return `false`. ("something" is always greater than "empty")
- If neither is empty, then you can compare `GetYield()`

Your comparison function returns `false`, `false`, `false`, and `GetYield()` for these four cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is wrong, safer is to rely on `std::tuple`/`std::pair`/`std::vector` comparison with appropriate projection;

```
const auto proj = [](const auto& p){ return std::pair{p.second, p.first.GetYield()}; };
while (true)
{
    auto it = std::max_element(items.begin(), items.end(),
                               [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
                                   return proj(lhs) < proj(rhs);
                               });
    if (it == items.end() || it->second == false) { break; }
    // do_job(it->first);
    it->second = false;
}
```